# How to add gem dependency to my ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, lita

I think I am fundamentally missing something. I am learning ruby, and have been playing with Lita lately, and wrote(my first) a simple little gem to get some directions/distance from the bot.  The problem I am having is where to put a gem dependency in my gem.  To work, my gem requires the 'rest-client' gem.   Where do I put this in my code so that it is available to my Directions class?  Currently, to get it to run, I am requiring the gem in my bots actual gemfile. And when I bundle exec lita, it apparently becomes available for my gem to use... but if I remove it from there, I can't get it to work anywhere in my gem.. what am I missing?  It is here if anyone wants to read the code and tell me where I should be adding it:

https://github.com/cashman04/lita-directions

EDIT:
I added the dependency like spickermann suggested. Then had to add require 'rest-client'to my directions.rb. Not entirely sure if this is the correct way, but it works now.  Thanks for the help spickermann

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following line into your `lita-directions.gemspec` right next to the one that defines the dependency on lita:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'rest-client'
```

Comment: Ok. I had tested that at one point, but I think I had the >= "1.0" after. I was just guessing at that point. Testing it now though.